# How to export QTableWidget data to Excel using Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I'm trying to pass data from a QTableWidget to Excel. Why in Excel is only the last row of the table written? (In print, the complete table is shown).

```
rowCount = self.QTableWidget.rowCount()
columnCount = 5

for row in range(rowCount):
    rowData = []
    for column in range(columnCount):
        widgetItem = self.QTableWidget.item(row, column)
        if widgetItem and widgetItem.text:
            rowData.append(widgetItem.text())
        else:
            rowData.append('NULL')
    print(rowData)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=rowData)
df.to_excel('Table.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Can you please display, the end result of rowdata? Or at least a part of it

Comment: ['332920', 'Ana', 'Rio Grande do Sul/RS', 'True', 'False']
['34', 'Cleiton', 'Piauí/PI', 'True', 'False']
['123546', 'Fernando', 'São Paulo/SP', 'True', 'True']
['563', 'Heber', 'Bahia/BA', 'True', 'False']
['1234567', 'João', 'São Paulo/SP', 'True', 'False']
['123682', 'Jorge', 'Paraná/PR', 'True', 'False']
['12345', 'José', 'Ceará/CE', 'True', 'False']
['52', 'Leticia', 'Espírito Santo/ES', 'True', 'False']
['1234', 'Marcelo', 'Pernambuco/PE', 'True', 'False']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a list of lists to hold all the rows:

```
rowCount = self.QTableWidget.rowCount()
columnCount = 5

# add this line
data = []

for row in range(rowCount):
    rowData = []
    for column in range(columnCount):
        widgetItem = self.QTableWidget.item(row, column)
        if widgetItem and widgetItem.text:
            rowData.append(widgetItem.text())
        else:
            rowData.append('NULL')
    print(rowData)

    # add this line
    data.append(rowData)

# change these two lines
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_excel('Table.xlsx', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: It didn't work now it gives an error and doesn't create excel, before created Excel but I just added the last line

Comment: @Fernando What error? I tested it, and it works perfectly for me. Are you sure you're running the same code as in my answer? I have added some comments to show the four lines that I changed.

Comment: @Fernando Can you please confirm that my answer works for you? As I say, I have fully tested it, so I know that it works properly. Please make sure you use the same code that is shown in my answer.

Comment: I don't know why it's not generating excel anymore, I copied and pasted the code

Comment: @Fernando What error messages do you see? Are you sure you're looking in the right place for the file? It will be in the current working directory. Perhaps you should try using a full (i.e. absolute) filepath instead.

Comment: (i.e. absolute) thanks it worked